# Partial functions application and folds in haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to learn Haskell by solving exercises and looking at others solutions when i'm stuck. Been having trouble understanding as functions get more complex.

```
-- Ex 5: given a list of lists, return the longest list. If there
-- are multiple lists of the same length, return the list that has
-- the smallest _first element_.
--
-- (If multiple lists have the same length and same first element,
-- you can return any one of them.)
--
-- Give the longest function a suitable type.
--
-- Examples:
--   longest [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]] ==> [1,2,3]
--   longest ["bcd","def","ab"] ==> "bcd"

longest :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t [a] -> [a]
longest xs = foldl1 comp xs
  where
    comp acc x | length acc > length x = acc
               | length acc == length x = if head acc < head x then acc else x
               | otherwise = x
```

So foldl1 works as follows - `input: foldl1 (+) [1,2,3,4] output: 10.` As I understand it, it takes a function applies it to a list and "folds" it. The thing I don't understand is that `comp acc x` compares **two lists** and outputs the larger length **list**.

The thing I don't understand is with `longest xs = foldl1 comp xs`. How are **two lists** provided to comp to compare and what is foldl1 "folding" and what is the **start** accumulator?

Here is another shorter example of another fold that I thought I understood.

```
foldl -  input: foldl (\x y -> x + y) 0 [1,2,3] output: 6
```

It starts at 0 and adds each element from left one by one. How does foldl exactly apply the `two variables` in the anonymous function. For instance if the anonymous function was (\x y z-> x + y + z) it would fail which I don't yet understand why.

Comment: `foldl1 f (x:xs)` is the same as `foldl f x xs` (it's a bit more involved for an abstract Foldable but the idea is the same).

Comment: You're folding a list *of lists*. The elements of the outer list are lists themselves.

Comment: When you do `foldl1 (+) [1,2,3,4]` how are **two numbers** provided to (+) to add and what is foldl1 "folding" and what is the **start** accumulator?

Comment: do you have anything at all to learn from, except for these exercises and the solutions to them written by "others"? have you ever seen the definition of `foldl` on lists?

Comment: @WillNess I try to learn from free available ressource https://haskell.mooc.fi/part1#lecture-1-and-so-it-begins and looked for the solution to this because I was stuck. I read the definition on fold but could not understand how and with which elements in the list it would begin to use compare function and apply fold to the rest of the list.

Comment: what about https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function), https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Foldable, https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative ....

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+fold+list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your current notion of what `foldl1/foldl` does is not quite accurate. As others already explained `foldl1 f (x:xs) == foldl f x xs` so the first value in the list is taken as an accumulator.

You say that `foldl1 (+) list` takes each value of the `list` "one by one" and computes the sum. I think this notion is misleaing: Actually you do always take two values, add them and get an intermediate result. And you repeat that over and over again with one of the values being the intermediate result of the last. I really like following illustration:

[image]

[Source](https://cs.famaf.unc.edu.ar/%7Ehoffmann/pd18/martes23.html)

If you start to think about these intermediate values, it will make more sense that you always get the largets one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easiest to understand if you look at a symbolic example:

```
foldl k z [a, b, c] = k (k (k z a) b) c

foldl1 k [a, b, c] = k (k a b) c
```

As you can see `foldl1` just starts with the first two arguments and then adds on the rest one by one using `k` to combine it with the accumulator.

And `foldl` starts by applying `k` to the initial accumulator `z` and  the first element `a` and then adds on the rest one by one.

The `k` function only ever gets two arguments, so you cannot use a function with three arguments for that.